# Dashed line not showing HTML, PHP, MySql

Tags: php, html, css

I have a database that is out putting a specific row. My code does that but I want a dashed border around it for my table. The code below should make a dashed line around this row but I don't know why it not working. Can someone help?

```
$count = 1
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr> <th>Pos</th> <th>Team</th> <th>PLD</th> <th>W</th> <th>D</th> 
<th>L</th> <th>F</th> <th>A</th> <th>GD</th> <th>PTS</th> </tr>";
// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

if($count == 5) {
 echo "<tr style='border-style:dashed'><td>"; 
 echo $row['Pos'];
echo "</td><td>"; 
echo $row['Team'];
echo "</td><td>"; 
echo $row['PLD'];
echo "</td><td>"; 
echo $row['W'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['D'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['L'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['F'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['A'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['GD'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['PTS'];
echo "</td></tr>"; 

 }
 else {
  echo "<tr><td>"; 
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Direct styling of  is not allowed.
You should put the border on the  elements and use border-right and border-left to remove the border in between columns.

```
<tr>
  <td style="border: 1px dashed black; border-right: none">Left</td>
  <td style="border: 1px dashed black; border-left: none; border-right: none">Middle</td>
  <td style="border: 1px dashed black; border-left: none; border-right: none">Middle</td>
  <td style="border: 1px dashed black; border-left: none">Right</td>
</tr>
```

You really should use html classes and a CSS file though.